# How can I use a custom DevTools theme in Chrome v114.0.5735.134?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, themes

I'm trying to use the [Zero Dark Matrix DevTools theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-theme-zero-dark/bomhdjeadceaggdgfoefmpeafkjhegbo) in Chrome 114.0.5735.134 (Official Build) (32-bit emulated) and am getting nowhere.

I have searched both Google and this site for answers to this question, but have come up with nothing but seemingly-outdated information that suggests the existence of an "Allow custom UI themes" setting within the DevTools Experiments tab, but no such setting seems to exist in the most-recent stable build (as of the time of writing).

The theme extension's overview page (linked above) also mentions an "Enable Developer Tools experiments" flag within chrome://flags, but that seems to have been fully integrated as a stable feature some time ago.

What gives?! Has Google completely dropped support for custom DevTools themes? MTIA :-)

Comment: The experimental option still exists: `Allow extensions to load custom stylesheets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by wOxxOm in the comments, the `Allow extensions to load custom stylesheets` setting within the DevTools Experiments settings is the only thing that now needs to be turned on.

I had already found this by myself several hours before posting, but this is the **really** crucial step: **restart Chrome** after enabling this setting!

I can't believe I was so close yet so far away, and all because I was too silly to think of the most obvious thing! Anyway I hope this helps someone else in the future ;-)